# How to prevent call to onStop() on screen lock

Tags: android, android-service, activity-lifecycle, android-broadcastreceiver

My app has certain functionality that I call in the `onStop()` method i.e. when I switch between apps.

It has a `videoview` so I want to switch it to audio only when I switch the apps.

I've implemented this in the `onStop()` method but when the screen gets locked it calls the `onStop()` and my app starts background audio playback.

**I want to retain the activity when screen gets locked and not switch to background audio playback.**

I tried using a `broadcast receiver` to capture the screen-lock event, but it captures the event after onStop() has been called.

I need help to **prevent calling `onStop()`** when screen gets locked or any way to **detect the screen lock event before calling the `onStop()` method.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check in `onStop` whether the screen is off or not. If it is on, simply switch to audio, otherwise do nothing (but don't forget to call the super of onStop).

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    if (pm.isScreenOn()) {
       // switch to audio
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. It worked but the isScreenOn() method is deprecated. Is there a new method or replacement for it?

Comment: Yes, I know that it is deprecated, but if you look at the source code (eg.  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/os/PowerManager.java#PowerManager.isScreenOn%28%29), you can see it returns the value from the new isInteractive() method where isScreenOn() is deprecated. So the simplest way to call isScreenOn(), it will work on all api levels (5 and above maybe)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can't **prevent** calling `onStop` when the screen locks. It will be always called when the `Activity` goes from visible to invisible state.

Yes, you can detect lock screen:

```
KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
  if( myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
      //it is locked
  } else {
    //it is not locked
  }
```

this won't work if screenlock is set to none in settings -> security -> screenlock.

Edit 1:
If you want to use `PowerManager`:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
if (pm.isInteractive()) {
   // the device is in an interactive state.
}
```

Edit 2:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

boolean screenOn;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
    screenOn = pm.isInteractive();
} else {
    screenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
}

if (!screenOn) {
    // screen is Off.
}
```

Comment: Should I use this in onStop() or in a broadcast-receiver?

Comment: Use this in `onStop`, that would be better.

Comment: The solution by @nvi9 below works and even when the screen lock is set to none.

Comment: @ShivamArora, look at the edited answer. This is not deprecated.

Comment: The isInteractive() method requires api level 20. But my app requires min api level 16. So it won't work perfectly. Though, I've upvoted your answer as it was useful. Thanks.

Comment: @ShivamArora, You can include both `isInteractive()` and `isScreenOn()` for different APIs level.